# How to install intel hd graphics 3000 and nvidia geforce 610m

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel

My laptop is Asus A45v with core i3, nvidia geforce 610m, 6bg ram
How to install in Ubuntu : intel chipset and nvidia graphics?
Thanks if you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intel drivers already are installed - install the NVIDIA drivers and Optimus.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Use NVIDIA X Server Settings to switch between Intel and NVIDIA graphics.

Comment: my nvidia 610 ,,, same tweak or not

Comment: @MuhamadYusup : I guess you mean the number : 352 is the drivers version suitable for NVIDIA 610M. :)